# How to extract files from request body in a HTTP Triggered azure function in C#

Tags: c#, post, azure-functions

I want to send multiple JSON files via POST request to my HTTP Triggered Azure Function (written in C#) at once. I can't understand how to extract those files from the request body. I am being able to get their contents as a string using `StreamReader` but that's pretty much it. I need to store the files as objects or something in a List so that I can pass it to another function for processing. I am also open to creating a map <file name, file content as string>. Any solution or relevant documentation links will be very useful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are answering your own question in the question. What is stopping you from doing any of your ideas?

Comment: @Fildor I can't access the filenames. How will I make a map?

Comment: I don't know. You are giving no information in your question that would enable us to give you any advice whatsoever. Try and come up with a [mcve].

Comment: Can [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoxEJii70_I) help you? See 14:29 code with IFormFile.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my testing result:

[image]

And this is the code:

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<div>
    <form asp-controller="File" asp-action="index" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Home controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication0528.Controllers
{
    public class FileController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;

        public FileController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            this.hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<string> IndexAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file != null) {
                string uploadsPath = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "css");
                string uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file.FileName;
                string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsPath, uniqueName);
                //file.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
```